# How to get the content of an file?

Tags: javascript

I have a File object, and i can access the name of the file, it's size, it's type and the last modified date, but i can't find the content of the file...

How to access the content of an file via the File object?

Comment: In node.js or in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FileReader`.

```
var fr = new FileReader;
fr.onload = function() {
    const text = fr.result;
    console.log(text);
};
fr.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked perfectly. (I can't accept your answer right now, in 5 min stack overflow is going to let me accept it)

Comment: @Gabriel Happy to help.